# Copy every nth column in Excel

Tags: excel

I've got one workbook with 27 worksheets containing ID numbers, Student name and email addresses.
Each separate sheet is one subject.

I want to copy column A from every sheet so that I can paste all the IDs into one column.
I have looked at the Consolidate Function, but it still requires me to select all the ranges I want to consolidate which is time consuming, as that would mean selecting 27 ranges. I also want to be able to keep all the subject lists separate so that I can still pick and choose which of the 27 sheets I want to combine.

I am able to select all sheets to delete columns, change column headers etc but when I select all sheets and select the column I want to copy (in my case, each column A from every sheet) it will only copy the values from the sheet that I'm currently in, even though all the other column As are also selected.

TLDR: Is there a way I can consolidate large numbers of sheets without selecting the ranges individually? I'm on a work computer so I can't download 3rd party apps.

Comment: I would use the [Get & Transform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-transform-in-excel-881c63c6-37c5-4ca2-b616-59e18d75b4de) feature in Excel (>= 2016 or with addin Power Query in some former versions). Look for "consolidate Excel sheets with power query" on the web

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new sheet. Then write all the Sheet-Names in the first row and then you can extract the first column of each sheet with this formula (put it in A2 and drag across and down as suited):

`=INDIRECT(A$1&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(A1),1))`